# Kalman filtering - latitude longitude needs to be converted to meters?

Tags: gps, velocity, coordinate-transformation, kalman-filter, utm

I have to implement kalman filtering to filter latitude longitude(from a gps sensor) to get precise position information.
i would be getting distance traveled from a wheel sensor and angle from magnetometer or i can also use gps course from gps sensor. I have latitude longitude in degrees or radians and distance in meters.
So before applying the kalman filtering i need to convert this lat/lon to meters, correct?
With this information i think i can predict using the following equation

```
x=x+dt*xVelocity;
y=y+dt*yVelocity;
```

I can calculate velocity using the following formula

```
xVelocity=distance*cos(angle);
yvelocity=distance*sin(angle);
```

So the problem here is the conversion. i tried to convert the above lat/lon to UTM and then performed the above calculation and just for testing converted it back to lat and lon to give the desired location but the results seemed wrong
For example-

```
double latitude=24.55662435;
double longitude=55.3525234;
double north,east;
latLonToUTM(latitude,longitude,&north,&east);
int distance=5;//5 meters
int course=200
double xVel=distance*cos(course);
double yVel=distance*sin(course);
north+=yVel;
east+=xVel;
double nxtLat,nxtLon;
UTMtoLatLon(north,east,&nxtLat,&nxtLon);
double distance=calculateDistace2LatLon(latitude,longitude,nxtLat,nxtLon);// Used online tool to get this distance
double bearing=calculateAnglebetween2LatLon(latitude,longitude,nxtLat,nxtLon);//used online tool to get angle also
```

here the obtained distance is not 5m and angle is 200..
Since this basic test itself is failing i am yet to go to kalman filtering.
First this conversion should be precise to even go further.
Can someone guide me to which method to use to convert this lat/lon to meters to apply velocity to get nxt meter or location?
Also if there is no need to convert then how can we add the distance travelled which is in meters to this lat lon?

Comment: I recommend working in ECEF coordinates. The WGS84 datum is used by GPS so if you elect that datum, you'll have plenty of resources available to you. This site provides simple code: http://danceswithcode.net/engineeringnotes/geodetic_to_ecef/geodetic_to_ecef.html

Comment: You might then want to go one step further and convert ECEF to ENU coordinates. That conversion is straightforward and is covered here: https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Transformations_between_ECEF_and_ENU_coordinates

Comment: ENU coordinates are nice for Kalman filtering of a vehicle. When doing the dynamics update, you'd use horizontal velocity to propagate the horizontal position coordinates (E and N). In the vertical coordinate, you can assume zero velocity during the dynamics propagation. Instead, inflate the vertical position uncertainty in the process noise matrix.